# Как из NSURL получить комментарии (comments) файла

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

В macOS для каждого файла можно написать комментарий. Например в Get Info.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С помощью метода:

```
 NSDate *date = nil;
 [url getResourceValue:&date forKey:NSURLCreationDateKey error:nil];
```

я могу получить дату и время создания файла а также другую дополнительную информацию. Но я не нашел как можно с помощью этого метода получить комментарий. 
Также рассматривал возможность получить комментарии файла c помощью методов `NSFileManager`:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:nil] fileSize];
```

но и тут тоже безуспешно.

Подскажите пожалуйсто как я могу получить комментарий файла.
Всем заранее спасибо.

Comment: может это поможет https://code.google.com/archive/p/openmeta/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ был найден на другом форуме.

Комментарий из файла можно получить вот так:

```
NSMetadataItem *originalFileMetadata = [[NSMetadataItem alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"file/path"]];
NSString * comment = [originalFileMetadata valueForAttribute:@"kMDItemFinderComment"];
NSLog(@"%@ ", comment);
```

Answer (score 0):

Это не публичный API это нужно делать через AppleScript или AppleEvent.

Штука называется Spotlight comment.